# Dúvida no carregamento da aquisição do rest para a view

Tags: node.js, rest

estou seguindo uma vídeo aula e surgiu uma dúvida.

criei duas pastas uma para o front (que é executado pelo servidor http-server porta 8080)

segunda pasta para o back ( que é executado pelo nodemon porta 3000)

mas infelizmente não carrega as coisas do back para o front... segue meus códigos se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda, por favor.

```js
/*PASTA front arquivo main.js*/
(function () {
    'use strict';
    
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/user/maria');//esse trecho de código não altera nem com nome invalido que n tenha no objeto do js do back.
    ajax.send();
     
    ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(ajax.responseText, ajax.status);
        }
    }, false);

})();


/* PASTA back arquivo index.js */
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

var users = {
    joao: {
        nome: 'Joao',
        idade: 30
    },
    maria: {
        nome: 'Maria',
        idade: 22
    },
    fernando: {
        nome: 'Fernando',
        idade: 20
    }
    
};

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.send('<h1>Home</h1>');
});

app.get('/user', function (request, response) {
    response.send('User');
});

app.get('/user/:username', function (request, response) {
    var username = request.params.username;
    if(users[username])
        return response.json(users[username]);
    response.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado'});
});


app.listen(3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> AJAX </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> FRONT </h1>
        <script scr="/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas o que acontece ? Dá algum erro ? Não aparece nada na página ? Qual dos urls é que não funciona ? Todos ?

Comment: Dei f12 não apareceu nenhum erro no console. 
Não apareceu nada em nenhuma das urls. 

Vi que no brackets aparece alguns uns erros.     
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();    //reclama do XMLHttpRequest()


var express = require('express'); //reclama do require
var cors = require('cors');

executei o comando npm install -g require-install o erro persiste